# Using WalletConnect via Gnosis Safe iOS throws an error when signing a message

Tags: react, gnosis-safe, walletconnect, authentication

I'm working on an authentication feature for my app and using [wagmi](https://wagmi.sh/) for the ethersjs interactions. I have two-step authentication flow: connect wallet and [SIWE](https://docs.login.xyz/general-information/siwe-overview). This entire process works fine with MetaMask, but when I use WalletConnect I receive an error after connecting the wallet with WalletConnect+Gnosis Safe iOS here while trying to sign a message:

```
      const message = new SiweMessage({
        domain: window.location.host,
        address,
        statement: 'Sign in with Ethereum to the app.',
        uri: window.location.origin,
        version: '1',
        chainId,
        nonce: state.nonce,
      })

      const signature = await signMessageAsync({
        message: message.prepareMessage(),
      })
```

the error is

```
{
    "code": -32000,
    "message": "Method not found"
}
```

When I try same process with Gnosis Safe Web, I see the signature popup in the app with no problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS app doesn't support signing messages at the moment